# Regular Expression to accept decimal numbers but not single 0

Tags: asp.net, validation

I am using `ASP.NET Regular Expression Validator` to validate a `textbox`.

**Valid Samples:**

```
1

1.1

11.1

11.12

0.1


0.12
```

**Invalid Samples:**

```
0

1.123
```

As you can see I don't want the input to contain only `0`.

Currently I have this expression which is allowing `0`.

```
^[0-9]{1,2}([/.][0-9]{1,2})?$
```

What can I do to prevent a single 0?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Writing a regexp that accepts anything but `0`, `.0`, `0.0` and `0.00` is complicated. Is there no other way than using a regexp? (I wrote an answer but deleted it because it failed on e.g. `0.01`)

Comment: @AndersAbel Gavin provided a pattern ,I could  not understand it completely , but works for me.Thanks for effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How does this work for you?

```
((?=.*[1-9])\d+(\.\d+)?)
```

Explaination:

`(?=.*[1-9])` - Matches but excludes anything greater than 1

`\d+` - Matches any digit

`(\.\d+)?` - Matches a decimal point plus the remainder.

Ignore the second grouping, this is just to break the regex up.

Comment: I will try this,thanks ,but can you explain a bit?Would be helpful.Thanks.

Comment: +1 for this.It works well for me thanks.a bit of explanation will be perfect.Thanks.

Comment: `Match a suffix but exclude it from the capture. [.*[1-9]]`

Answer (score 0):

(((?=.*[1-9])\d+)((.\d{1,2})?))$

Also Work i.e.

-> 1.5

-> 20.80

-> 5.45

-> 0.5