# Regular Expression to test for single zero

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation

I'm trying to write a regular expression in ASP.NET to test for the following numeric values:

```
1      valid
1.23   valid
12.45  valid
123.01 valid
0.56   valid
012.89 valid

0.123  invalid
1.     invalid
1.1    invalid
1234   invalid
0      invalid
```

I've created the following regular expression that satifies all the above except if the user supplies a single 0.

```
^[0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{2})?$
```

I've tried extending the expression to prevent a single 0:

```
^(?!0{1})[0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{2})?$
```

This works, but then 0.56 is invalid. I can't work out how to test for just a single 0, but ignore this if there are other numbers present.

Comment: Maybe this one? `^[1-9][0-9]{2,3}(\.[0-9]{2})?$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of: [Regular Expression to accept decimal numbers but not single 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11826034/regular-expression-to-accept-decimal-numbers-but-not-single-0)

```
^((?=.*[1-9])[0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{2})?)$
```

verified by http://rubular.com/r/hm3FE5pLFd

edit: note that this expression doesn't match `0.00`.

Comment: Thanks for this. I wasn't aware I could use ?=.*[1-9] to test for the zero.

Comment: That's quite a tricky RE! The key to understanding it is that a positive lookahead does not consume characters. In other words, `(?=.*[1-9])` checks to ensure the string contains a non-zero digit (anywhere in the string) and then the matching starts at the first character of the string with `^([0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{2})?)$`.

Comment: Thank you for the warning note. I actually had an attempt to convey this message in an edit, but I couldn't find the right wording.